# Javascript Object.length based on key of last object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have a list of filters to be applied to a data set using a simple `key:value` loop. When the user selects a filter, a new object is created with those `key:value` pairs. However, if there are 4 filters, and the user has selected only the 1st and 3rd filter items, the new object that is created is structured like this:

```
var newObject = {
  0: {
    key: value,
  },
  2: {
    key: value,
  }
}
```

When I call `newObject.length`, it returns `3`. See the following from Chrome devtools:

[image: devtools object description]

`Object.length` seems to be based off of the last key in the object, rather than the number of objects themselves. How can I get the `newObject.length` to return 2 instead of 3?

Here is my function that creates the object based on the filters:

```
selectedInModel: function() {
  var selected = [];
  var getInputs = inputService.primaryInputs; // returns filter object
  for (var key in getInputs) {
    if (getInputs[key]["value"]) {
      selected[key] = {
        "value": getInputs[key]["value"],
        "id": getInputs[key]["id"]
      };
    }
  }
  return selected;
};
```

How can I get `Object.length` to return the *number* of objects in my object?

Comment: Note object don't have a `length` property by default. Arrays do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `[]` as an object. `length` should give you the highest index regardless of how many properties. I would switch to using an object instead:

```
var selected = {};
selected[key] = {
    "value": getInputs[key]["value"],
    "id": getInputs[key]["id"]
};
Object.keys(selected).length;
```